# In Go, why does exec.Command() fail but os.StartProcess() succeed launching "winget.exe"?

Tags: windows, go, winget

- `exec.Command()` works for executing `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`
- But `exec.Command()` doesn't work for executing `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe`. Fails with the error message:

  - `exec: "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\winget.exe": file does not exist`
- However, `os.StartProcess()` works for executing `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe`

Can someone tell me why?

This code fragment does not work. `winget.exe` isn't launched.

```golang
wingetPath := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"),
    "Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\winget.exe")
cmd := exec.Command(wingetPath, "--version")
err := cmd.Start()
fmt.Println(err)
// exec: "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\winget.exe": file does not exist
```

But this works:

```golang
wingetPath := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"),
    "Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\winget.exe")
procAttr := new(os.ProcAttr)
procAttr.Files = []*os.File{nil, nil, nil}

// The argv slice will become os.Args in the new process,
// so it normally starts with the program name
_, err := os.StartProcess(wingetPath, []string{wingetPath, "--version"}, procAttr)
fmt.Println(err)
// <nil>
```

#### Go version:

```sh
> go version
go version go1.18 windows/amd64
```

Comment: Shot in the dark hypothesis - but does the redacted `<username>` contain a space within it?

Comment: @selbie no it doesn't

Comment: @SachinJoseph not sure but curious, your error is `file does not exist` so you can debug by using `filepath.Abs` or `filepath.WalkDir` to get the paths in your expected directory, see if anything is different there and use that path instead, if that helps.

Comment: @code0x00 this is caused by a bug in the Windows implementation of Go. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874620/1724702).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bug in Golang

So apparently this is a bug in the Windows implementation of `Go` and has been filed on GitHub many times - the oldest I could find is this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42919) which was filed years ago.

The bug is caused by the fact that `exec.Command()` internally [uses](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cb702a2a5670d4fa599f573b37b1a01abc9f995a/src/os/exec/lp_windows.go#L19) `os.Stat()` which does not read files with [reparse points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) correctly. `os.Lstat()` can.

Windows Store apps use [App Execution Aliases](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/#QBVyMPUOpI9SMbFI.97), which are essentially zero-byte files with reparse points. This [post](https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html) has some additional details.

### Workarounds

- Workaround is to use `os.StartProces()` - a lower level API which can be a bit painful to use especially when compared to `os.Exec()`.

  **Important**: In `os.StartProcess()`, the argv slice will become `os.Args` in the new process, so you should normally pass the program name as the first argument:

```golang
wingetPath := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"),
    "Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\winget.exe")
procAttr := new(os.ProcAttr)
procAttr.Files = []*os.File{nil, nil, nil}
/*
To redirect IO, pass in stdin, stdout, stderr as required
procAttr.Files = []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}
*/

args = []string { "install", "git.git" }

// The argv slice will become os.Args in the new process,
// so it normally starts with the program name
proc, err := os.StartProcess(wingetPath,
   append([]string{wingetPath}, arg...), procAttr)
fmt.Println(err) // nil
```

- Another approach to work around this bug is to (create and) execute a `.cmd` file (for example) which would (correctly resolve and) execute the file with reparse points. See [this](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/pull/5874) (and also this [directory](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/tree/master/sdk/python/dist)) for an example.